# On possible closures of the derivative operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}:  L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ be the one-dimensional Laplacian, considered as an unbounded, densley defined operator with domain $\mathcal D(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}) = C^\infty([0,1])$ the smooth funtions *without* boundary conditions.

**Question 1: Can one explicitly describe the domain $\mathcal D((\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^*)$ of the adjoint operator ?**

By means of partial integration, one easily checks that

a) $B := \{ f \in C^2([0,1]): f(0) = f'(0) = f(1) = f'(1) = 0 \} \subseteq \mathcal D((\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^*)$, so that $(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^*$ is densely defined (in particular, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ is closable).

b) $(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^*|_{B} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}|_{B}$.

c) The restriction $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}|_{B}$ is symmetric and densley defined, hence closable.

By c), we may consider the minimal closure $\overline{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}|_{B}}$. Now since $(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^*$ is a closed extension of $(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^*|_{B} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}|_{B}$ by b), we must have $\overline{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}|_{B}} \subset (\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^*$.

**Question 2: Do we have the equality of closed operators $(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})^* = \overline{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}|_{B}}$. If not, what is their difference ?**

Comment: Q2 : Yes, the two operators are the same.

Comment: (b) is not true.